# var is firing before triggering through button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have the following situation:

```
<a href="#" id="trigger">CLICK ME</a>
```

and

```
  var x = alert("test");
  $('#trigger').click(function() {
      x
  });
```

Why is `x` firing on loading the page, and not while pressing the button? I know when placing the variable into the function it works, but I don't really get why!

Comment: I suggest you to [learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript) on the MDN to understand what functions do.

Comment: really i dont get why someone is downvoting if this is a normal question! i guess my js, jquery is okay and its just i needed to get it in mind!

Comment: your JS is not okay. You don't know JS, you only want to get past it by just learning jQuery

Comment: the case is the same! and dont try judging me by that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var x = alert("test");
```

This will execute `alert("test")`, then assign the value of that expression to `x`. (`alert` doesn't return anything, so `x` will be set to `undefined`.)

Instead, use this code:

```
var x = function() {
    alert("test");
}
$('#trigger').click(function() {
    x(); //remember to actually call it!
});
```

Here are some better ways:

```
$('#trigger').click(x); //no need to wrap in function if it does not have
                        //any arguments
$('#trigger').on('click', x); //using on
```

Comment: or better yet, `$('#trigger').on('click', x)`

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
var x = alert("test");
```

you actually call the function and put its *return value* into the variable x. As `alert()` has no return value besides `undefined` there is nothing really stored in `x`.

That's why the next time you access `x` it is still empty and does *not* contain a pointer to a function or something similar!

Answer (score 1):

`var x = alert("test");` will call the function `alert("test")` immediately, and then assign the return value to `x`.

To get the behavior you desire, you can wrap the call to alert in a function:

```
var x = function() {
    alert("test");
}
```

And then to call it later, use parentheses (a parameter list):

```
$('#trigger').click(function() {
      x();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `alert("test")` is a function which will show an alert message. Since you call this function not in the `$('#trigger')` area, it has nothing to do with the click functionality of the trigger but will be executed as soon as the script part is executed by your browser.